# Service Constructor Call behaves different than Method Call in the Constructor

Tags: angular, methods, behavior

**This is about Google Geocoding**

`@agm/core` asks, to construct an instance  of `google.maps.Geocoder` in your service  ?  You have to  inject a `MapsAPILoader` instance, and use its load promise to make a delayed call to `google.maps.Geocoder()`, after some magic has completed behind the curtain.

**Class**

```
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core'
export class GeocodingService 
{
  private geo : any; 
  constructor(private mapLoader: MapsAPILoader) {}
  ..
}
```

**Version a)**

```
constructor(private mapLoader: MapsAPILoader) 
{
   this.mapLoader.load().then
   { 
      this.geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
   }
}
```

**Version b)**

```
constructor(private mapLoader: MapsAPILoader) 
{
  this.getgeo();
}

private getgeo() 
{
   this.mapLoader.load().then
   { 
     this.geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
   }
}
```

**Version a) does not work**

> core.js:6014 ERROR
>      Error: Uncaught (inpromise):
>      ReferenceError: google is not defined at new GeocodingService (GeocodingService.ts:53)

**Version b) does work**

What is the difference? For me a) and b) seem to be equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/maps-api-loader-eg), you can try this out.
I hope this helps.

If still seeing the same issue, fork it and let me know